# Missing bullet points when using unicode-math in beamer

Tags: beamer, xetex

I'm using XeLaTeX on TeXShop trying to set up a presentation with the Beamer class, and wanted to take advantage of the Zapfino font in the frame titles. If I'm understanding correctly, in order to do so I need something that looks like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,serif]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\usepackage[light,math,condensed]{kurier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{family={\fontspec[Variant=1]{Zapfino}}, size=\small}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A title}
    text
    \begin{itemize}
    \item this is an item
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Now, when I compile this document I do get the Zapfino font in the frame title, but I lose the bullet points in the `itemize` list. I believe the problem lies in the use of the `unicode-math` package, as the following code will compile, will restore the missing bullet points BUT clearly won't allow the use of the Zapfino font in frame titles.

```
\documentclass[11pt,serif]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\usepackage[light,math,condensed]{kurier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{unicode-math}
%\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{family={\fontspec[Variant=1]{Zapfino}}, size=\small}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A title}
    text
    \begin{itemize}
    \item this is an item
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

(Commenting `\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{family={\fontspec[Variant=1]{Zapfino}}, size=\small}` is necessary as otherwise the code won't compile.)

I've also tried to work round the problem in an artisanal way by using a `description` list and manually inputting bullet points, but it didn't work either. It's like those characters were completely missing.

Is there a way around this or am I forced to choose between the frame titles and the bullet points?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Don't use inputenc with xelatex. And if your file is really applemac encoded you will have to inform xelatex with a \XeTeXinputencoding command.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to use `kurier` along with `unicode-math`. If you look at the output you get, it *doesn't* use Kurier.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the `unicode-math` package.  Removing that and loading `fontspec` directly gives you both the Zapfino fonts and your bullet.  In the code below I have also corrected the call to the `serif` font theme in beamer, removed the `inputenc` as in Ulrike Fischer's comment and altered the loading order of the packages (everything font related has to be loaded after `fontspec`):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage[light,math,condensed]{kurier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{family={\fontspec[Variant=1]{Zapfino}}, size=\small}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A title}
    text
    \begin{itemize}
    \item this is an item
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output]

Comment: Which doesn't use the Kurier font.

Comment: Thank you very much, Andrew. That helped the frame titles and the bullet points coexist. It is true however what, @egreg says, i.e. that my choice of font is ignored. May I ask why is that? Thanks again!

Comment: @egreg Quite right.  I have corrected this so the Kurier font is used.  It was a problem with the loading order of the packages.