# Alternative to "Missing bullet points when using unicode-math in Beamer"

Tags: beamer, unicode-math

I know, there is already [Missing bullet points when using unicode-math in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72792/missing-bullet-points-when-using-unicode-math-in-beamer) but the only and accepted answer *"**Do not use unicode-math**"* is not what I need because I'd like to change my math font as well and, in my understanding, this requires `unicode-math`.

So, my question has *at least* two types of possible answers

1. How  to tell Beamer to use a different mechanism for bullet points and don't care for `unicode-math`.
2. How to specify a font for math without using `unicode-math`

Here it is my setup (I'm using XeLaTeX)

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=149]{beamer}
\usefonttheme[onlylarge]{structurebold}
\usecolortheme[RGB={150,0,80}]{structure} 
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
%%%%%% FONTS
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Numbers=Lining]{Cambria}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text,Numbers=Lining]{Calibri}
\setmonofont[Scale=0.95]{Consolas}
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}
%%%%%% /FONTS
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Definitions}
  Let's start with some math
  \[\alpha(\tau)=\sin(\beta\tau)\]
  and some definitions
  \begin{itemize}
  \item adj., constantly changing
  \item noun, the branch of Mechanics concerned with the
    motion of bodies under the action of forces
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

and the same file compiled with luaLaTeX
[image]

---

and here the uuencoded version of the gzipped log file (I cannot post the file itself because it exceeds the 30,000 char limits in SE posts).

Editors note: removed the uuencoded gzip log and replaced it with the relevant snippets. The full log can be found in the edit history. The missing character [U+25B6](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25b6/index.htm) is a 'BLACK RIGHT-POINTING TRIANGLE'.

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019/Debian)  (format=lualatex 2020.3.5)  5 MAR 2020 18:49
 restricted system commands enabled.
**puffo.tex
(./puffo.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
Lua module: luaotfload-main 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload entry point
Lua module: luaotfload-init 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / initialization
Lua module: lualibs 2020-02-02 2.70 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2020-02-02 2.70 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended collection.
Lua module: luaotfload-log 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / logging
Lua module: luaotfload-parsers 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / filelist
Lua module: luaotfload-configuration 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / config file reader
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is /home/boffi/.texlive2019/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic-dev/names.
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader "fontloader-2020-01-26.lua" from kpse-resolved path "/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontloader-2020-01-26.lua".
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@state = 2
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 3
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@syllabe = 4
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version "3.11"
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor\' at position 1 in `pre_linebreak_filter\'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor\' at position 1 in `hpack_filter\'.
Lua module: luaotfload-loaders 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / callback handling
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font\' at position 1 in `define_font\'.
Lua module: luaotfload-database 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / database
Lua module: luaotfload-unicode 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / Unicode helpers
Lua module: luaotfload-colors 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 5
Lua module: luaotfload-resolvers 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / resolvers
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is /home/boffi/.texlive2019/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic-dev/names.
Lua module: luaotfload-features 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / features
Lua module: luaotfload-letterspace 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua module: luaotfload-embolden 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua module: luaotfload-notdef 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / color
Lua module: luaotfload-auxiliary 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / auxiliary functions
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens\' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_font\'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_font_index\' at position 2 in `luaotfload.patch_font\'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh\' at position 3 in `luaotfload.patch_font\'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata\' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_font_unsafe\'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight\' at position 4 in `luaotfload.patch_font\'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_xheight\' at position 5 in `luaotfload.patch_font\'.
Lua module: luaotfload-fallback 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / fallback
Lua module: luaotfload-multiscript 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / multiscript
Lua module: luaotfload-script 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / Script helpers
Lua module: luaotfload-tounicode 2020-02-02 3.12 luaotfload submodule / tounicode
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname\' at position 6 in `luaotfload.patch_font\'
. L3 programming layer <2020-02-25>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamer.cls
Document Class: beamer 2019/09/29 v3.57 A class for typesetting presentations

[...many lines skipped here...]

Package fontspec Info: Font family \'Cambria(0)\' created for font \'Cambria\'
(fontspec)             with options
(fontspec)             [Ligatures=TeX,Mapping=tex-text,Numbers=Lining].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - \'normal\' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"Cambria:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;+tlig;+lnum;"
(fontspec)             - \'small caps\'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"Cambria:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;+tlig;+lnum;+smcp;"
(fontspec)             - \'bold\' (b/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"Cambria/B:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;+tlig;+lnum;"
(fontspec)             - \'bold small caps\'  (b/sc) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"Cambria/B:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;+tlig;+lnum;+smcp;"
(fontspec)             - \'italic\' (m/it) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"Cambria/I:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;+tlig;+lnum;"
(fontspec)             - \'italic small caps\'  (m/scit) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"Cambria/I:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;+tlig;+lnum;+smcp;"
(fontspec)             - \'bold italic\' (b/it) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"Cambria/BI:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;+tlig;+lnum;"
(fontspec)             - \'bold italic small caps\'  (b/scit) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"Cambria/BI:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;+tlig;+lnum;+smcp;"

Package fontspec Warning: Input mapping not supported in LuaTeX.
(fontspec)                 Use "Ligatures=TeX" instead of "Mapping=tex-text".

[...many lines skipped here...]

Missing character: There is no \xe2\x96\xb6 (U+25B6) in font CambriaMath:mode=base;script=math;language=dflt;!
Missing character: There is no \xe2\x96\xb6 (U+25B6) in font CambriaMath:mode=base;script=math;language=dflt;!

[...a few more  lines skipped here...]
```

Comment: Works fine for me in a current tex system. The output looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyttM.png.

Comment: Might be an idea to post the exact log for your compilation of this MWE

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Good morning Ulrike, I'm updating my system, let's see if my problem disappears...

Comment: @daleif I'm in a hurry just now, but in the Italian afternoon...

Comment: @Ulrike I have updated TeXLive on my Debian Sid but nothing changed. I have edited my Q adding the log of the compilation.

Comment: @daleif I'm going to post the log of the compilation now.

Comment: That is not the log but the terminal output. But beside this: Try with lualatex. It gives better log-files when fonts are involved.

Comment: Works fine for me too. I use recent MikTeX installation and  XeLaTeX engine. The output is the same as show @UlrikeFischer in her comment.

Comment: I have updated my TeXLive installation (using Debian Sid packages) and I still see the problem, both in XeLaTeX and in LuaTeX...

Comment: With my old TeX Live 2017/Debian it also works without problems (both with triangles and with squares).

Comment: @Marijn Thank you for the edit and for spotting the problem.  In light of other people stating "no problem for me" I now guess that I'm using an old and /or incomplete version of Cambria Math.

Comment: @Marijn Would you like to add a short answer mentioning the issue with old/incomplete Cambria Math I'd be glad to accept your answer.

Comment: @Marijn OK, I've voted to close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [simple workaround](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11168/change-bullet-style-formatting-in-beamer#comment112344_11170) is

```
\setbeamertemplate{items}[square]
```

and it seems to me that the problem lies in an old version of Cambria Math that does not include the BLACK RIGHT-POINTING TRIANGLE gliph.

---

My modified example

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=149]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{items}[square]
\usefonttheme[onlylarge]{structurebold}
\usecolortheme[RGB={150,0,80}]{structure} 
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
%%%%%% FONTS
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Numbers=Lining]{Cambria}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text,Numbers=Lining]{Calibri}
\setmonofont[Scale=0.95]{Consolas}
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}
%%%%%% /FONTS
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Definitions}
  Let's start with some math
  \[\alpha(\tau)=\sin(\beta\tau)\]
  and some definitions
  \begin{itemize}
  \item adj., constantly changing
  \item noun, the branch of Mechanics concerned with the
    motion of bodies under the action of forces
  \end{itemize} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and the output

[image]

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/483631/blacktriangle-not-showing-if-unicode-math-included for other solutions.